# Check if constructor does exist at compile time

Tags: java, reflection

I am mapping a hibernate query to an object using a constructor like this :

```
Constructor<Product> contructor = Product.class.getConstructor(String.class, String.class, Integer.class, String.class, String.class, String.class,
                        String.class,String.class, String.class,Boolean.class);
criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer(contructor));
```

If someone modify the constructor by adding a parameter, this code will fail but at runtime. It is possible to insure at compile time that the Contructor that we need here realy exists ?

Comment: You would have to modify the compiler for a compile-time analysis, so no, I do not think there is a way. You could, however, use the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java) and reinforce the presence of a factory method with corresponding parameters by defining an interface and letting the Factory-class implement that interface (but that only moves the problem... what if someone changes the interface definition?...).

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You may as well just check as soon as possible (in a static block in the main class).

Comment: it might help if you used AliasToBeanResultTransformer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically what tests are for.

For example:

```
@Test
public void constructorAvailableTest() {

    try {
        Constructor<Product> contructor = Product.class.getConstructor(String.class, String.class, Integer.class, String.class, String.class, String.class,
            String.class,String.class, String.class,Boolean.class);
    } catch( NoSuchMethodException nsme ) {
       fail( "The specified " + Product.class.getName() + " constructor does not exist!");
    }

}
```

Better yet, you could put the code that reflexively constructs the Product in a static method and just call that in your test!

Comment: @RC How? Doesn't he want to test his own code, not hibernate's?

Comment: I meant the snippet he posted